# How to make an export DISPLAY?

Tags: java, scripts

I'm execution a Java project on a distant server. My project generates a graphical interface. Here is the shell script that I'm executing on the server side :

```
export PATH=/user/java6/jre/bin:/usr/java6/bin:$PATH
export DISPLAY=[my_IP_adress]:0.0
java -jar /home/user/my_user_name/Projet_Interface.jar
```

It generates the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The project is built using Ant. The same error was generated when I run on Eclipse IDE, while it's running successfully with Netbeans.

So I suppose that the error has someting related to the command line `java -jar` that must be adapted to `ant` on the script. Am I wrong?

Comment: What's the OS you're using on your side?

Comment: It may be an xserver access permission issue. There is a command "xhost" to manage that. If you do "xhost  +" at the command line it will give anyone access to your xserver. That may solve the problem.

Comment: to sort out security issue, try xclock to see if xclock id dispaly where you expect java script to run.

Comment: `NullPointerException`! Could you confirm that `export DISPLAY= [my_IP_adress]:0.0` has no space between `=` and the IP?

Comment: @Sneetsher no there is no space

Comment: Nameless, could you please give the output to the following command: `java -version&&uname --kernel-release&&lsb_release --code --short`

Comment: @nameless: Can you please post the full stack trace of the exception, so we can get a better idea, which component causes it?

Comment: @nameless I edited the question to remove  the space after the `=` in `export DISPLAY= [my_IP_adress]:0.0`  to for reducing confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar file was copied without the resources it depends on. I resolved the problem by copying all the Java project on the right location.